# Flex : where to find a free spider/radar chart component?

Tags: apache-flex, charts, components

i'm building my first RIA in flex, and did a little of research to find a radar chart component free, but all i found is not free (licence >500$).

Where can i find it for free ?

I'm student and i'm learning flex, so there is no point of buying component for now.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [BirdEye](http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/), it has radar charts in different flavors.

Comment: The library is good, but has almost zero documentation. Have u been able to figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

There is another one here : http://lab.kapit.fr/display/radarchart/Radar+Chart